# Affine if reduction is affine

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, schemes, affine-schemes

If I have a scheme $X$ and an ideal sheaf $\mathcal{I}$ consisting of nilpotent elements such that the closed subscheme of $X$ cut out by $\mathcal{I}$ is affine, is $X$ affine?

Comment: Yes; see [EGAI, 5.1.9]. It's also in Hartshorne, Exc. III.3.1, although for Hartshorne's argument you need noetherianity, since you use Serre's criterion for affinity. [This answer](http://mathoverflow.net/a/102/33088) and the cited paper by David Rydh also mentions the result is true for algebraic spaces.