# Prove that Scheme $X$ Affine consider $X$ reduced

Tags: algebraic-geometry

My question refers to a comment in following former thread of mine:[Reduction Technique to consider Reduced Scheme](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2678574/reduction-technique-to-consider-reduced-scheme)

Let $X$ be scheme. If I want to prove that $X$ is affine why can I assump that $X$ is reduced, therefore $X= X_{red}$ ?

Comment: In the Noetherian case, this is exercise III.3.1 in Hartshorne. The point is to use Serre's cohomological criterion for affiness and then do induction on the 'size of the nilradical'. To be precise, you want to induct on the integer $n$ such that $\sqrt{(0)}^n=0$, which exists because $X$ is Noetherian. Here by $\sqrt{(0)}$ I mean the ideal sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$ consisting of nilpotent elements.

Comment: So this "trick" here only works if $X$ Noetherian?

Comment: I think it is still true in general. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1948469/affine-if-reduction-is-affine and the link to mathoverflow found in this answer.